# how to create aro using dbAcl using console

Tags: cakephp

i am using cakephp for my project but whille creating acl using command promt.
when i run the following command  **cake schema run create DbAcl** it genrate three tables in database. but after puting the following code in users_controller.php. and this command. **cake acl view aro**
 it dont create aros.

function index()
    {

```
$aro =& $this->Acl->Aro;
//pr($aro); exit;
//Here's all of our group info in an array we can iterate through
$groups = array(
    0 => array(
    'alias' => 'admins'
    ),
    1 => array(
    'alias' => 'guests'
    ),
    2 => array(
    'alias' => 'mangers'
    )
);

//Iterate and create ARO groups
foreach($groups as $data)
{
    //Remember to call create() when saving in loops...
    $aro->create();
    //Save data
    $aro->save($data);
}
       }
```

Comment: i have windows and i could never get cakephp console to work. i just do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create your AROs you need to create a view for your index method in the UsersController and after that visit Users/index in your browser. Only after that call `cake acl view aro` from console. If that doesn't help try to use this [tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bancer/). It provides user friendly way to create your aros (groups and users) and acos (menus) and manipulate them.